# Regular expressions: any except given phrase

Tags: php, regex

`[tag]blabla[/tag]`

I would like to replace it to:

`<tag>blabla</tag>`

But leave it unchanged if there is a phrase "leavemealone" between `[tag]` and `[/tag]`.

So `[tag]leavemealone[/tag]` or `[tag]aaa leavemealone[/tag]` or `[tag]aaa leavemealone aaa[/tag]` etc. should be unchanged.

Code:

```
preg_replace("#\[tag\](what_should_be_here)\[\/tag\]#", "<tag>$1</tag>", $text);
```

Comment: @WaleedKhan, is this really helpful? Perhaps answering his question will help him more in the end (we don't know his constraints ^_^).

Comment: "Don't parse markup with regexes." - great comment, now everything's clear (...)

Comment: @geehertush01: It's good advise though. Properly parsing markup with regex gets ugly really fast.

Comment: Why not capture the phrase between `[tag]` and `[/tag]`, which can be done using a regex if you like, and operate the substitution if and only if the captured string does _not_ contain `leavemealone`? If you really want to use a regex anyway, have a look at negative lookaheads.

Comment: Simple replacing operations like this **can** be achieved more easily with Regular Expressions.

Comment: @geehertush01 At the end Waleed Kahn is right. The main point is, that in fact you can't evaluate something like HTML, or BBCode with regular expressions properly, because both are not regular languages. For now it may work, but sooner or later it will break and even worse: The more complex it becomes, the more likely you will introduce security issues. Parse the content to a syntax tree instead.

Comment: @KingCrunch Ok, thanks for the **explanation**, I'll keep that in mind. Anyway, you can achieve simple things (that's what I needed) with RE.

Comment: @geehertush01 Seems, that you didn't get the main point: You can open your server for the whole world, when you apply re on _userinput_ without knowing, what you are doing. It will probably be very easy to inject javascript and stuff.

Comment: @KingCrunch Really? Show me then how you can inject "javascript and stuff" when I use eg. this `preg_replace("#\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]#s", "<b>$1</b>", $user_input)` (assuming of course, that I filter "<" char). And "without knowing, what you are doing" you can mess up a lot, not only with RE.

Comment: @geehertush01 You filter `<` completely? So whats about a simple ":>"-smiley? Or something like "Only in XY < 1.2"? Of course re are not the only one, with what you can break things completely, but it's incomparable easy with it, because the more cases you want to cover, the more complex it will get. For example whats with "don't replace anything in `[code]`"? Thats the point from my first comment: Sooner or later it doesn't work anymore the way you want. At the end it's up to you. I've made this experience several years ago and I thought it's useful to share :)

Comment: @KingCrunch By "filter" I didn't mean to remove "<" completely, but to replace it with "&lt;" for example. I get your point and I agree, that for complex parsers using RE is a very bad idea. But if you only want to add possibility of bolding the text or puting a link, I think there's nothing wrong with using RE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following patterns.

```
$match = "#\[(\w+)\](?!.*leavemealone.*)(.*?)\[/(\w+)\]#";
$replace = "<$1>$2</$3>";
```

And that should do it. If you don't want to match any tag, but just a "`tag`" tag, you can fix it up like this:

```
$match = "#\[tag\](?!.*leavemealone.*)(.*?)\[/tag\]#";
$replace = "<tag>$1</tag>";
```

Comment: Are you sure about your replace value?

Comment: @fge No, I'm getting the impression that replace expressions don't use delimiters?

Comment: You've included regex delimiters on the replace value. Also I think .* is making it somewhat confusing in the lookahead. Other than that, that's the way to go

Comment: I've fixed the delimiter. @caiosm1005: What do you mean? Is there a better way?

Comment: The OP didn't mention there could be anything other than `leavemealone` inside the tags, also we're not sure how much experience he has with RegExp, so using .* in this case could be deceiving ;)

Comment: @caiosm1005 I guess you mean the second one? Yes, it is indeed not needed.

Comment: @caiosm1005 "The OP didn't mention there could be anything other than leavemealone inside the tags" <-- yes he did.

Comment: @caiosm1005: I'm still confused as to what you're talking about.